# my app in java throws an exception that says Invalid BSON field name Name

Tags: java, mongodb

I have this code:

```
public class UpdateShoe {

MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("MirandasShoes");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("Shoes");
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();

public void UpdateShoe(Shoe sfilter, Shoe snew) {
    Document sfilterdoc = new Document();
    sfilterdoc.append("_id", sfilter.getId());
    sfilterdoc.append("Name", sfilter.getName());
    sfilterdoc.append("Brand", sfilter.getBrand());
    sfilterdoc.append("Type", sfilter.getType());
    sfilterdoc.append("Color", sfilter.getColor());
    sfilterdoc.append("Size", sfilter.getSize());
    sfilterdoc.append("Price", sfilter.getPrice());
    
    Document snewdoc = new Document();
    snewdoc.append("Name", snew.getName());
    snewdoc.append("Brand", snew.getBrand());
    snewdoc.append("Type", snew.getType());
    snewdoc.append("Color", snew.getColor());
    snewdoc.append("Size", snew.getSize());
    snewdoc.append("Price", snew.getPrice());
    
    this.collection.updateOne(sfilterdoc, snewdoc);
}
```

}

When I hit the update button, it throws the excepion that says Invalid BSON field name Name.
In the intellisense it specifies that the parameters have to be bson and I am using document but in the online documentations document is mostly used so why is it throwing the exception, is there something wrong in my code?

This is the console output when I hit the update button:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name Name
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.writeName(AbstractBsonWriter.java:532)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterDecorator.writeName(BsonWriterDecorator.java:193)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:198)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:141)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:403)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:375)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writeDocument(BsonWriterHelper.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writePayload(BsonWriterHelper.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:147)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandMessage.encode(CommandMessage.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:248)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:450)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:218)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeCommand(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:435)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeBulkWriteBatch(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.access$700(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:205)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:196)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReleasableConnection(OperationHelper.java:501)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:196)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1048)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeUpdate(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1032)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:617)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.updateOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:612)
    at DAL.UpdateShoe.UpdateShoe(UpdateShoe.java:45)
    at UI.UpdateShoeUI.btnUpdateShoeActionPerformed(UpdateShoeUI.java:162)
    at UI.UpdateShoeUI.access$100(UpdateShoeUI.java:18)
    at UI.UpdateShoeUI$2.actionPerformed(UpdateShoeUI.java:79)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Please post the _stack trace_ of the generated exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have mentioned is equivalent to:

```
db.col.updateOne({"_id":"id"...etc.},{"name":"newName"...etc.})
```

You are missing the `$set` command here. So what you need to do is this:

```
Document snewDoc = new Document();
snewdoc.append("Name", snew.getName());
snewdoc.append("Brand", snew.getBrand());
snewdoc.append("Type", snew.getType());
snewdoc.append("Color", snew.getColor());
snewdoc.append("Size", snew.getSize());
snewdoc.append("Price", snew.getPrice());
Document updateDoc = new Document("$set",snewDoc);
this.collection.updateOne(sfilterdoc, updateDoc);
```

The above is equivalent to the correct format, which is:

```
db.col.updateOne({"_id":"id"...etc.},{"$set":{"name":"newName"...etc.}})
```